# I need to upload and read image files to folder that is not part of my project folder Asp.NET MVC 5. My site is hosting in IIS server. Any idea?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload and read image files to folder that is not part of my project folder. My site is hosting in IIS server. I have already save files in my project folder. There's no an issue. But I need to change that to outside folder. How can I do this? I'm using .NET 4.5.2.

### This is what I using now

```
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(objdata.image.FileName);
                string imagepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/SupplierImages/"), filename);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(imagepath);
                }

                objdata.image.SaveAs(imagepath);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to save files to another folder?  Does this fail in any way?

Comment: With this method, I can save and read files if folder is inside my project root. But I need to get it outside.  'Server.MapPath' is not working for outside path.

Comment: Well, yes, because [`Server.MapPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath) is to map relative paths *inside* the web project to their corresponding file system paths.  What happens when you just use the actual file system path where you want to save the file?

Comment: I get this error. I made new folder inside my IIS root. Then tried to save files inside that. 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SupplierImages/' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Comment: What specifically is throwing that error?  That sounds like something that `Server.MapPath` would throw, but you shouldn't be using that.

Comment: Assuming you figure out the correct path, you also need to make sure the built-in IIS_IUSRS group has permission to the folder or [set an app pool identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) that has the correct permissions

Comment: There is no error when I not using `Sever.MapPath` . I tried with direct path. But `System.IO.File.Exists()` is return false with this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I need to change that to outside folder. How can I do this?

You'd change it to another folder by changing it to another folder:

```
string imagepath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Whatever\folder\you\want", filename);
```

Comment: This is the best answer on Stack Overflow, ever.

Comment: Yes sir. But how to check file is exists or not with this way? Does `System.IO.File.Exists()` accept this path to check?

Comment: @Darshana: You'd check if the file exists by using `System.IO.File.Exists()` and passing it the path of the file to check.  Have you *tried*?

Comment: Yes sir. But it return false. Let me try again.

Comment: @Darshana: `false` is an expected return value.  You are encouraged to [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists) to see what it means.  It would return `false` if the file doesn't existor if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string.  Unless you have some specific indication as to why a `false` result is unexpected, "it return[s] false" doesn't really describe a problem.

Comment: Sir it's working well now. Thanks! Have a good time!